# Switch language in article with laravel localisation without change the slug

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application in two languages french "fr" and english "en".
I have a button who manage the language En/Fr when i click on button the page when the user visited change to the other language. 
My base url is like that http://example.com/en/ and http://example.com/fr/
I use this code and is working well to switch betwenn the two languages for the base url (my home page)

```
@if(\App::getLocale() == "fr")
      <a hreflang="en" href="{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL("en", null, [], true) }}"><img src="{{url('images/lang.png')}}" width="30"></a>
      @else
      <a hreflang="fr" href="{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL("fr", null, [], true) }}"><img src="{{url('images/lang.png')}}" width="30"></a>
      @endif
```

For home page http://example.com/en/ is okay. But when the user looking page like this one in website http://example.com/en/myfirstarticle/ when i hit the button/link of language, the language change well, but redirect me in the home of other language http://example.com/fr  when i want to be redirect here http://example.com/fr/myfirstarticle/.

Someone can help me ?
Thank you

Comment: need more explanation

Comment: @AashifAhamed i have a two languages application i have a button when i hit is switch bettween the two languages.  when im home page is okay. But when im in other page of my application is not working im redirecting in the home page.

Comment: Could you try `{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL('fr') }}`, so passing `false` for  [$forceDefaultLocation](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/blob/master/src/Mcamara/LaravelLocalization/LaravelLocalization.php#L258)

Comment: @Remul try this but not working. I have the same result.

Comment: you need to set parameter for that current url (myfirstaricle). I've never using localization, but I think that is the problem.